# Can deploy but not debug .NETCF 3.5 App to Device

Tags: visual-studio-2008, debugging, compact-framework, embedded, windows-ce

I have a software application written for .Net Compact Framework 3.5 in VS2008. I can connect to my device via Activesync and deploy the application without problems. I can launch the app on the device after deployment without a problem.  However, if I try to connect and debug the app, I get an unhelpful message that says "A serious error has occurred" and I lose my debug connection.

Has anyone encountered something similar?  Any ideas on what to check first?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have all service packs for Studio installed.

Comment: I'm all caught up - double checked against multiple PC's as well.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you discovered the VS2008 debugging limit. If your target heap goes over 32MB you are screwed.

you can check this:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/kb/973905
but it didn't work for me.

I removed heap intensive stuff like static objects, strings, bitmaps, yadda yadda and that's fine until you hit the 32MB wall again.
PITA.

Good Luck